# How can I display all my existing records in Mysql from Django database?

Tags: mysql, django

I migrated the Django database model to MySQL. When I tried to access the data in MySQL, I can't seem to find my existing data. How can I fix this?

Migration code:

**settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sample',
        'USER': '********',
        "PASSWORD": '********',
        'HOST': '*****',
        'PORT': '*****',
        'OPTIONS': {
        'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import os
from PIL import Image
from datetime import date
import datetime
from .validators import validate_file_extension
import base64
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.html import format_html



def get_directory_path(instance, filename):
    today = date.today()
    t = datetime.datetime.now() 
    day, month, year = today.day, today.month, today.year
    hour, minutes, seconds = t.hour, t.minute, t.second
    filename = str(day) + str(month) + str(year) + str(hour) + str(minutes) + str(seconds) + '.png'
    dir = 'media'
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, filename)
    return path


class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_directory_path, null = True , validators=[validate_file_extension])
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

After this, I typed:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Everything seems to work well but I'm not able to view my data. Any suggestions?

Comment: migration only migrate db structure , no data which was present in tables .

Comment: Migrate from what db to MySQL? Is this just development or do you have production data? Do you really need to migrate the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you using sqlite before? After changing the database and migrating only the database schemas(tables) are made in MySql. You will loose all your data from before and cannot retrieve it.

Comment: That's something which I wasn't aware of. Thank you

Comment: If you also want the data from sqlite then use DB browser for sqlite to export your data into .sql file then import that file from Mysql import option in your migrated database.

Comment: Oh, I'll make sure to try that in the future. Thank you